# How to store value in variable having special character and linux command in php

Tags: php, linux, magento

I want to use below in php:

```
$cmd = '<'.$filePath.' tail -f  +'.$lineNumber.' |  grep "tracker.php" | cut -d" " -f1-8';

$data = shell_exec($cmd);
return $data;
```

but there is something wrong in storing value of $cmd variable.

If you simply echo value of cmd variable then also it is getting printed.

Someone faced this type of issue before?

Comment: What is the `<` ???

Comment: And you can't run `tail -f` from within PHP.

Comment: This command I am using for reading log from specific line to end of file, REF: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517140/use-grep-command-to-read-a-file-from-specific-line-number-to-end-of-file/517147#517147